# Error in calling Microsoft vision API from C++

Tags: c++, azure-cognitive-services

I want to call Microsoft Vision API from C++ and I am using [cpr library](https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr) to make requests. Now I'm run the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cpr/cpr.h>
#include <json.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    auto response = cpr::Post(
        cpr::Url{"https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/analyze"},
        cpr::Body{{"url","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/12/Broadway_and_Times_Square_by_night.jpg/450px-Broadway_and_Times_Square_by_night.jpg"}},
        cpr::Header{{"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "xxxxxxxx"}}
    );
    std::cout << response.status_code ;
    auto json = nlohmann::json::parse(response.text);
    std::cout << json.dump(4) << std::endl;
}
```

Though the code is running by `cmake`, so `make` was successful. But when I executed the executable, the following error appeared:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
what():  basic_string::_M_create
Aborted (core dumped)
```

PS: the documentation for Microsoft Vision API can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/python)
So, tell me if I am doing some mistake. Also if someone know that how to send http requests in QtQuick app please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
auto my_json = nlohmann::json::object({
    { "url","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/12/Broadway_and_Times_Square_by_night.jpg/450px-Broadway_and_Times_Square_by_night.jpg" }
});

response = cpr::Post(
    cpr::Url{"https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/analyze"},
    cpr::Body{ my_json.dump() },
    cpr::Header{{"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "XXXXXX"}}
);
```